# Checkbox switch state not changing when retrieved value from db using PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a front end HTML configuration form, when the checkbox switch is set to 1 it means this configuration is active, when it's 0 the configuration is inactive, the insert and update is working as expected, only the current state of the checkbox switch when the page is refreshed is always set to enabled, this is regardless on if the db value is 1 or 0, how can I correct this?

The checkbox state is stored in the configuration_status table

My PHP file is:

```
<?php

require 'credentials/credentials.php';

// Retrieve the email designer configuration information from the database
$mysqli = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
  error_log("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
  die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//get the current values from the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM configurations WHERE key_name IN ('smtp_server', 'port_number', 'username', 'password')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$configurations = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $configurations[$row['key_name']] = $row['value'];
}

// Retrieve the checkbox state from the settings table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM configuration_status WHERE config_key = 'email-designer'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$settings = $result->fetch_assoc();
$config_enabled = $settings['config_enabled'];

// Close the database connection
$mysqli->close();

// Update the HTML with the retrieved values
$smtp_server_value = $configurations['smtp_server'] ?? '';
$port_number_value = $configurations['port_number'] ?? '';
$username_value = $configurations['username'] ?? '';
$password_value = $configurations['password'] ?? '';

// Check if config is enabled
if (isset($_POST['config-enabled']) && $_POST['config-enabled'] == 1) ? 1: 0{
  $config_enabled_checked = 'checked';
} else {
  $config_enabled_checked = $config_enabled ? 'checked' : '';
}

?>
```

and my HTML is -

```
<form id="email-config-form" method="post" action="assets/php/email_config.php">
<div class="form-check form-switch">
    <label for="email-designer-enabled" class="form-check-label">Enable Email Designer</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="config-key" name="config-key" value="email-designer">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="email-designer-enabled" name="config-enabled" value="1"<?php echo $config_enabled_checked; ?>>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="smtp-server">SMTP Server:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="smtp-server" name="smtp-server" value="<?php echo $configurations['smtp_server']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="port-number">Port Number:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="port-number" name="port-number" value="<?php echo $configurations['port_number']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $configurations['username']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $configurations['password']; ?>">
</div>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const checkbox = document.getElementById("email-designer-enabled");

  // Set the initial state of the checkbox based on the value from the database
  if (checkbox.value === "1") {
    checkbox.checked = true;
  } else {
    checkbox.checked = false;
  }

  // Add an event listener to the checkbox to update the value in the database when the checkbox is clicked
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
    const newValue = this.checked ? "1" : "0";
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "email_config.php");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log("Value updated successfully");
      } else {
        console.log("Error updating value");
      }
    };
    xhr.send("config_enabled=" + encodeURIComponent(newValue));
  });
});
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="config-def" name="config-def" value="email-designer">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update">Update</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="insert">Insert</button>
</form>
```

I need the checkbox switch status to be the same value as whats stored in the DB, either 0 (disabled) or 1 (enabled)

Comment: Your checkbox has unconditional `value="1"`. Your JS always makes this checkbox checked. Start with commenting that JS fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is invalid syntax:

```
if (isset($_POST['config-enabled']) && $_POST['config-enabled'] == 1) ? 1: 0{
```

`? 1 : 0` is outside the `if()` condition, you can't put them there.

There's no need to test the value of `$_POST['config-enabled']`. Checkboxes are only sent when they're checked, so you only need the `isset()` test.

```
if (isset($_POST['config-enabled']) {
```